# Git on Windows- SSL certificate error

Tags: windows, git, ssl

There are many question related to this problem and much more answers. None of them works.
I have PortableGit and configured to use certificate from specific store. If I specify wrong file path, I get eror: "error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile"
As soon as I specify correct path, this error is not shown.

We are using our local CA authority. Local GitHub server is third in certificate chain. I added github server's certificate to certificate store. git clone stil does not work.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

CA store needs all certificates in certificate chain to be present.
I added **every certificate in certificate chain** to certificate store.
Note: Global gitconfig is located at "C:\PortableApps\GitPortable\mingw64\etc\gitconfig" (please adjust "C:\PortableApps\GitPortable\" to your system). I added following line to my local gitconfig

```
[http]
sslCAinfo = C:/PortableApps/GitPortable/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Local gitconfig is located at

> ~/.gitconfig

(c:\Users\xxx.gitconfig)